# Capturar número de excepción en C#

Tags: c#, excepciones, try-catch

Hola gracias por la ayuda, estaba pensando en capturar mediante un try catch todas las excepciones que ocurran en cada una de mis funciones, pero mi pregunta es como puedo acceder al código o al número de excepción de cada una de ellas, ya que he visto que se puede capturar el mensaje pero no encuentro acerca del número, espero haber Sido claro en la pregunta.

Comment: Porque querrias hacer algo asi? mas alla de que sirva como ejercicio, en la practica no es logico hacer algo con una excepcion, a menos que sepas como tratarla y como va a seguir tu programa cuando eso ocurra. Con el numero, a que te referis?

Comment: igual, creo que estas buscando lo que estaba en la documentacion aca ;) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.hresult?view=net-6.0